# Need to swap field visibility on a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, field

I'm trying to swap visibility of 2 elements based on a drop-down selection in the form.

If user selects any of the first 6 items, the "Message" area remains.

If user selections last item "Reproduction Rights", then "Message" disappears and is swapped with "Rights message" div.

I've got it working with the repro rights showing/hiding, but not the message box. I'm new to java, so pardon my ignorance. Here's the full page code or view at [Paul-Rand.com](http://www.paul-rand.com/site/contactus/):

**Got it working with this code, but is there a cleaner way to do it?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Paul-Rand.com :: Contact Us</title>
        {embed=site/meta}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{stylesheet=styles/twocolumn}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{stylesheet=styles/global}" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{path=scripts/livevalidation_standalone}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[
                function display(obj,id1,id2) {
                    txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
                    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
                    if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
                        document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
                        document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }
            // ]]>
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        {embed="site/mainNav"}

        <div id="container">

            <div id="centercontent">

                <h1>Contact Us</h1>

                <div class="form-left">
                    <p>To send us a message, please fill out the form below. We'll get back to you shortly!</p>

                    {exp:freeform:form
                    required="name|email|message"  
                    collection="Contact Form"
                    return="site/success"
                    notify="dlewandowski38@yahoo.com"
                    template="randContact"
                    file_upload="Email attachments"
                    send_attachment="yes" }

                        <label>Name / Company Name <em>(required)</em> 
                            <br style="clear:both">
                            <span><input type="text" name="name" id="Name" class="formMediumText"/></span>
                        </label>

                        <script type="text/javascript">var Name = new LiveValidation('Name');Name.add(Validate.Presence);</script> 

                        <label>Email <em>(required)</em>
                            <br style="clear:both">
                            <span><input type="text" name="email" id="Email" class="formMediumText"/></span>
                            <script type="text/javascript">var Email = new LiveValidation('Email');Email.add(Validate.Email );</script>
                        </label>

                        <label>Regarding
                            <br style="clear:both">
                            <span>
                                <select name="regarding" id="Regarding"  class="formMediumText" onchange="display(this,'subject','Reproduction Rights');">
                                    <option value="subject">General Inquiry</option>
                                    <option value="subject">Suggestion for the site</option>
                                    <option value="subject">Problem with the site</option>
                                    <option value="subject">Work to Share</option>
                                    <option value="subject">Story to Share</option>
                                    <option value="subject">Pictures to Share</option>
                                    <option value="Reproduction Rights">Reproduction Rights</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </label>

                        <div id="Reproduction Rights" style="display: none; float:left;background-color: #ff9900; padding: 20px;">
                            <h4 style="text-transform: uppercase; padding: 0; margin:0;">Reproduction rights are granted through the Paul Rand estate only.</h4>
                            <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">Contact the <a href="http://www.library.yale.edu/mssa/" target="_blank">Yale Archives</a> with a detailed description of your planned usage and they will process your request.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="subject" style="display: none">
                            <label>Message
                                <br style="clear:both">
                                <span>
                                    <textarea cols="24" rows="12" name="message" id="Message"  class="formMediumText"></textarea>
                                </span>
                            </label> 
                        </div>

                        <br style="clear:both"/>
                        <hr/>

                        <h2 style="margin-bottom:-18px">Help the site grow</h2>
                        <h5 style="margin-bottom:-6px">Have a piece of Paul Rand work that's not seen on the site? Share it! </h5>
                        <p>Send your files (any image type, 800px wide or larger), your name and website (if available). I'll add it to the appropriate gallery and give you credit for your addition.</p>
                        <p>Your contributions are GREATLY APPRECIATED!</p>
                        <br/>

                        <label for="file" style="float:left;">Share a File (up to 5 per message):</label>
                        <span><input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" class="formPicBrowse"/></span>
                        <span><input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" class="formPicBrowse"/></span>
                        <span><input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" class="formPicBrowse"/></span>
                        <span><input type="file" name="file4" id="file4" class="formPicBrowse"/></span>
                        <span><input type="file" name="file5" id="file5" class="formPicBrowse"/></span>

                        <br style="clear:both"/>
                        <br/>

                        {if captcha}
                            <label>For security, please enter the word you see below:
                                <br style="clear:both">
                                <p style="width:160px;">{captcha}</p>
                                <span><input type="text" name="captcha" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Security Code') { this.value = ''; }" value="Security Code" id="Captcha" class="formMediumText" style="width:130px" /></span>
                            <script type="text/javascript">var Captcha = new LiveValidation('Captcha');Captcha.add(Validate.Presence);</script> 
                            </label>    
                        {/if}

                        <br style="clear:both"/>
                        <br/>

                        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="buttons" style="font-size:18px; padding-top:8px;"/></p>

                    {/exp:freeform:form}  
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var Name = new LiveValidation( 'Name', {onlyOnSubmit: true } );
                    Name.add( Validate.Presence );
                    var Email = new LiveValidation( 'Email', {onlyOnSubmit: true } );
                    Email.add( Validate.Presence );
                    var Message = new LiveValidation( 'Message', {onlyOnSubmit: true } );
                    Message.add( Validate.Presence );
                    var Captcha = new LiveValidation( 'Captcha', {onlyOnSubmit: true } );
                    Captcha.add( Validate.Presence );
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        {embed=site/bottomSection}
        {embed=site/footer}
        {embed=site/googleTracking}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I'm new to java*. No, you are new at *JavaScript*. Java is a completely different language.

Comment: Updated the code with current working sample. Any cleaner, more proper way? Thanks!

Comment: Try jQuery http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For start it's good manners to clean your code to contain only the necessary bits before you post it here. It's difficult to wade through all of it in search of the relevant bits.

This isn't a JavaScript problem as such, just a plain logic issue. So what you want to do is a switch. If user selected `option a` set `div 1` visible and `div 2` invisible. If user selected `option b` do the opposite. Below is the modified display function

```
function display(obj) {
  txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
  if (txt.match("Reproduction Rights")) {
    document.getElementById("Reproduction Rights").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("MessageDiv").style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
     document.getElementById("Reproduction Rights").style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById("MessageDiv").style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

and the `HTML`to go with it. Two points to notice about this. You don't need the call to the `hide()` function in the `onchange` event handler, the `display` function is a switch, it'll do all the work. I also added a wrapping div with an id of `MessageDiv` to allow hiding both the message box and the text accompanying the message box. If the text isn't supposed to be hidden then by all means leave the div out.

```
<label>Regarding
<br style="clear:both">
<span><select name="regarding" id="Regarding" class="formMediumText" onchange="display(this, 'Reproduction Rights');">
<option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
<option value="Suggestion for the site">Suggestion for the site</option>
<option value="Problem with the site">Problem with the site</option>
<option value="Work to Share">Work to Share</option>
<option value="Story to Share">Story to Share</option>
<option value="Pictures to Share">Pictures to Share</option>
<option value="Reproduction Rights">Reproduction Rights</option>
</select></span>
</label>

<div id="Reproduction Rights" style="display: none; float:left;background-color: #ff9900; padding: 20px;">
<h4 style="text-transform: uppercase; padding: 0; margin:0;">Reproduction rights are granted through the Paul Rand estate only.</h4>
<p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">Contact the <a href="http://www.library.yale.edu/mssa/" target="_blank">Yale Archives</a> with a detailed description of your planned usage and they will process your request.</p>
</div>

<div id="MessageDiv"> 
<label>
Message <em>(required)</em>
<br style="clear:both">
<span><textarea cols="24" rows="12" name="message" id="Message"  class="formMediumText"></textarea><script type="text/javascript">var Message = new LiveValidation('Message');Name.add(Validate.Presence);</script>
</span>
</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Matti. Much appreciated. I'll be sure to clean out all unnecessary bits from now on. That thought process with the swap is exactly what I need to happen. I tried to use your code, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts? I'm using Chrome 8, not sure if that makes any difference. Thanks! ~D

Comment: @Danny: um,yeah - apparently I was clever enough to leave the `id1` hanging around on the line that should show the "Reproduction Rights" box. Updated code above.

Comment: Ahhhh, perfect! Thank you! Ok, so I now know how to define a specific id. Makes total sense now.